# what is the best way to simulate DDoS TCP SYN Flooding attack

Tags: simulation, ddos, ns-3

I want to simulate a network that is under DDoS TCP SYN Flooding attack and evaluate the performance of a new solution and compare it with other solutions.
i was planning to do it using NS3 but i read somewhere in the internet that i can't do it well using a descret event network simulator (NS3 is a descret event network simulator), i want to know why ? and what is the best alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, DoS attacks cannot be simulated in *ns-3*. By extension, DDoS attacks cannot be simulated either.

## How does a DoS attack work?

To understand why *ns-3* can't simulate a DoS attack, we need to first understand how a DoS attack works. As you mention, TCP SYN flooding is one way of simulating a DoS attack. Why does this work? Well, any computer had a finite number of resources, for example, memory and disk space. When a computer receives a SYN, it creates a socket to facilitate communication. Given that there are a finite number of resources, only a finite number of sockets can be created. So, a DoS attack works by overwhelming a computer on the network with SYNs, thereby forcing the computer to allocate many sockets that won't be used. At some point, the computer must simply refuse any connect, even legitimate connections. This is when a DoS attack has succeeded.

## Why can't *ns-3* simulate it?

In *ns-3*, there is no concept of a `Node` having finite resources, per say. `Queues` within `Nodes` can have finite size, but there is no way to limit the number of active connections on a `Node`. Ergo, there is no way to simulate a DoS attack.

## A (Potential) Solution

Contribute to *ns-3!* Visit the [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev), and try to add the functionality you desire.

---

## Response to Comment(s)

### TCP in *ns-3*

I was using "number of active connections" as equivalent to "number of sockets". These terms are not entirely equivalent, but for the purpose of this answer, it's okay.

In a SYN flood, the number of packets being received is *not* the concern. Rather, the problem is that each SYN received spawns a half-open socket, and only a finite number of sockets can exist on the computer.

You are suggesting saturating the `Queue` that receives packets. You could send a bunch of packets to saturate this `Queue`, and that *will* disrupt the `Node` to *some* extent, but this will not simulate a SYN flood. A SYN flood works because too many half-open sockets are spawned, not because a packet queue is full.

Again, a SYN flood works because a real computer can only have a finite number of sockets. In *ns-3,* there is no limit to the number fo sockets on a `Node`.

### The *ns-3* model

It seems that you may not be familiar with *ns-3*'s model. I don't blame you; there is a steep learning curve. In *ns-3*, a `Node` is the equivalent of a computer/server/router on the network. Attached to `Nodes` are `Applications`. In turn, `Applications` create `Sockets` to facilitate communication over a network.

Let's now look at `TcpSocket`, a subclass of `Socket`. `TcpSocket` maintains its state with the help of `TcpTxBuffer`, `TcpRxBuffer`, and other class variables. The `Buffers` are the classic buffers used by TCP to ensure reliable, ordered, and error checked delivery/reception of data. The size of these `Buffers` is limited, however **there is no limit to the number of `TcpSockets` attached to an `Application`, nor is there a limit to the number of `Applications` attached to a `Node`.** If such a limit existed, that would aid in simulating memory usage, but no such model exists in *ns-3*.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/B-m2QhveLGE) post on the *ns-3* Google Groups also describes why you can't simulate SYN floods without changing the source code. Search that Google Group for more posts about DoS attacks. The linked post describes how you may be able to simulate other types of DoS attacks, but SYN floods are not explicitly supported.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of why can't ns3 simulate it, starting from : but there is no way to ...., i don't want to limit the number of active connections, since queues within nodes have a finite size, i will simply allocate the entire queue by sending a barrage of packets

Comment: hmm, by saturating the queue i meant the queue of TCB, i can't imagine how in NS-3 there is no limit to the number of sockets, how is that possible ? is the TCP not implemented like in real world or there is something else ? thank you so much for your time

Comment: Can u give me the source of what you said, cuz i need it to justify my choice, Ididn't find about that in the official doc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think TCP-SYN Flooding attacks can be simulated at the current time.

I am currently also working on a simulation in ns-3 in which I would have liked to simulate a TCP-SYN Flooding attack. And I actually found [a paper] (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8448683) claiming to have implemented a SYN Flood in ns-3 successfully by just implementing a socket that sends SYN packets. Sadly the source code is not provided which makes me even more skeptical if  their implementation actually worked as described. While the [ns-3 documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/tcp.html) claims to implement the TCP state machine properly, which I do believe them, I am also inclined to believe @Sagar, since I couldn't find anything in the documentation about limiting the number of open sockets in any way.