# Is it possible to use python to control network simulation OMNeT++

Tags: python, c++, simulation, omnet++, ddos

I am currently working on the Data Science & DDoS simulation project. that's why I defiantly go with python. but there are no simulations on python ([ns3 not supporting for DDoS Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894176/what-is-the-best-way-to-simulate-ddos-tcp-syn-flooding-attack)). so I have choose OMNeT++. is it possible to transfer the data between python and OMNeT++ (based on C++)? like, send simulation input data from python. get the output data from OMnet to python.

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: can you explain or any tutorials about how to did this?

Comment: Asking for other resources like tutorials is off topic. Interprocess communication (IPC) usually is a whole chapter in a book. It's to broad to describe it here. Search for this keyword. Read about it. Choose one method. Try to implement it. If you get a specific problem you can come back and ask a specific programming question.